# How do I use an mdl badge to overlap an image?

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I am creating a website but have come across a problem. I want to create a sort of expanding gallery that expands when you hover over a cover image. I want the cover image to have a material design lite badge that says the amount of images in that gallery. My problem is that I cannot find a way for the badge to show up on an image. For some reason, it just doesn't work. My current workaround is this:
HTML:`<main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="gall1" class="material-icons mdl-badge mdl-badge--overlap" data-badge="2"></div>
  </main>`

CSS:`#gall1{
    background-image: url('20152016.png') center / cover;
}`

But it still is not working. Does anyone have any thoughts, solutions, or ideas as to why this is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to give a more complete demo that provides the various parameters you're working with. It might need to involve positioning, z-index etc., but your actual situation is unknown. Often I like to use `::before` /  `::after`` for this sort of thing.

Comment: http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#badges-section

Comment: Not sure what I'm supposed to look at there. :-(